# Storing categories and subcategories associated with a user

Tags: relational-database

I'm currently working on a web project using PHP and MySQL.
I'm facing a problem in MySQL and I need an advice.

I can fix my problem with two methods but I don't know which one is more efficient and faster than the other.

I need to store multiple categories and sub-categories associated to a specific user. There is no specific limit for how much categories and sub-categories users can have (it can be a large number).

1. First method, I add in the table of my user (MySQL) a column called `categories`, in which I save a serialized array from PHP with all those categories and sub-categories. 
   ex: `{1:Sports:badminton;2:Sports:baseball;3:Trip:Canada;4:Trip:USA;5:Trip:MEXICO;}`

The good side of it is that I can space space and it is more compact. 
The bad side of it is that I can't make any relations between my tables categories, sub-categories.

2. Second Method, I create a table called `user_categories` with columns `(entry_id, user_id, category, sub_category)` and I add every entry.

Ex:

```
╔═════╦═════════╦════════╦═════════════╗
║ 1   ║ VM1974  ║ Sport  ║ badminton   ║
║ 2   ║ VM1974  ║ Sport  ║ baseball    ║
║ 3   ║ VM1974  ║ Trip   ║ Canada      ║
║ 4   ║ VM1974  ║ Trip   ║ USA         ║
║ 5   ║ VM1974  ║ Trip   ║ Mexico      ║
║ 6   ║ MC1959  ║ Sport  ║ badminton   ║
║ 7   ║ MC1959  ║ Sport  ║ golf        ║
║ 8   ║ MC1959  ║ Trip   ║ Canada      ║
║ 9   ║ MC1959  ║ Trip   ║ USA         ║
║ 10  ║ MC1959  ║ Trip   ║ Mexico      ║
╚═════╩═════════╩════════╩═════════════╝
```

The good side is that I can make perfect relations between those tables.
The downside is that they will be a lot of entry in this `user_categories` when it starts to get more and more users...

So what could I do ?
Thanks

Comment: I changed your title to fix the grammar. I'm pretty sure I didn't affect the meaning, but you can roll it back if I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the second approach. If you'll use the first one, sometime you'll make a misprinting, and you database won`t be consistent any more.
Take a look on [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and you'll always know better approach.
If your categories are the same for different users, you'd bettercreate "categories" table with categories and "user_categories" with columns (entry_id, user_id, category_id). With such a structure you can easy count users in definite category. Also take a look on [enum](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) type and to databases with build-in json type (like [postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html))

Comment: Great thanks for your faster answers ! It also seems like the second option is the best.

Answer (score 0):

I like also your second approach!

Relations will be important for your further SQL joins and further analysis.

Another point is, that you must seralize your data always for every record and every step and cannot use your database.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have two entities here, and one (or maybe two) relations:

- `user`, which can have 0 or many activities
- `activity`, which has exactly one category. (Eg. Golf, which is a sport)

So I'd have three tables: one for users, one for activities (which has a `description` column and a `category` column) and one for the relation `user_activities`.

This last table just has `user_id` and `activity_id` and an entry in it means "this user does this activity". You might want a uniqueness constraint to ensure each user can only "do" each activity once.

Depending on your set up, you'll either want a separate table for the categories or not. If I were you, I'd be tempted to start simple and refactor `category` as it's own table when you feel you actually need to. (Like if you're querying a lot on `category` and your activities table has become huge.)